# JVM, Tomcat on 64 bit Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, 64-bit

On 32 bit systems, JVM has a memory limit of 1.5 to 2 GB. What is a good value of JVM memory on 64 bit Linux ? How that can be mapped to maximum number of threads and maximum requests in tomcat ?

I am using JDK 6+ and tomcat 7. RAM available will be 12 GB on a quad core processor.

MRD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an out of the box answer to this question. This depends heavily on what kind of applications you are going to host and how much is it going to be on your system. I administer a small server with 3-4 applöications on a 64bit linux system. Using 4GB is more than enough for me.

My advise is make a wild guess how much ram is required for your applications. Then startup tomcat with a monitor tool then watch how much load is there on your tomcat. You might have allocated too much resource for tomcat. Maybe too few. you never know

Please read this article on [Simultaneous users](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/simultaneous-users), and also the article about [load balancing in tomcat](http://people.apache.org/~mturk/docs/article/ftwai.html)

Basically you have to differentiate between users and requests. you might have 5000 users browsing your site, but only 100 making requests for a new page at one moment. By default tomcat supports 50 concurrent requests (not 100% sure though). But this number can be changed in your tomcat configuration. Obviously you might need more hardware.  In the second article, max 200 requests per tomcat instance is recommended. only simple calculation rules as mentioned in the second article and doing some monitoring can help.

There's even a load balancer manager for tomcat. Check it out
[load balancer for tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html)

One more thing to think of, is although you have the hardware and the right load balancing to support 5000 users, you also need enough bandwidth to do so. Again explained in the second article "load balancing in tomcat"

Good luck

Comment: I posted detailed requirement and questions in another thread and that thread got closed :( Anyways ... It would be helpful if you tell how much % of RAM can be kept for JVM memory on a 64 bit Linux system. I have got answers like not more than 70% of your physical RAM or 70% of the remaining after subtracting your OS memory etc. What is your suggestion ? Also, how that will map to number of maximum threads of tomcat ?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to support 5000 concurrent users. Depending on above calculations, I will calculate how many web servers I should add under a load balancer.

Comment: 5000 concurrent users with one application server, do you use AIX machine? <br>I do not think one machine can support so many requests, unless your app serve is simple.

Comment: @meadlai I want to estimate how many servers I need based on average amount of load handled by one server.

Comment: btw. I believe its better to ask server related questions on http://serverfault.com/, which is server forum for stackoverflow

Comment: those articles are really helpful. we are considering 5000 users requesting at the same time. hence this is going to be heavy traffic site. currently site has 10-15K daily users, during peak time there are around 100-120 simultaneous requests. we have kept 200 max threads and 400 max connections on 32 bit windows hosted tomcat. it runs fine. but now we are designing it for 300K daily users hence decided to move to amazon cloud.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many users will visit you application simultaneously.

Sometimes, the app will run very slowly at a particular time point,

For instance, at 8:00 AM, login action causes the app can't stand.

I suggest you to estimate average memory per user, according the “total number of users",

Then you may get a nearly almost RIGHT memory setting.

---

Comment: for the memory left for OS, you'd better check your SWAP on the OS.

Comment: please read the comments for the answer above for sizing estimation.